# Django, new model raises error when trying to access the server

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model, Which is new:

```py
from django.db import models


class Point(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Latitude",
                                 blank=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Longitude",
                                  blank=False)
    elevation = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Location's Elevation",
                                  blank=True)


class Location(Point):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='create')

    location_name = models.TextField(verbose_name="Location Name",
                                     blank=False,
                                     unique=True,)
    location_info = models.ForeignKey(Point,
                                      related_query_name='new_location',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      blank=False,
                                      )
```

I ran makemigrations and migrate and didn't ran into any errors.
when running the server I got the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /points/
column NewLocationModel_location.point_ptr_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...location" INNER JOIN "NewLocationModel_point" ON ("NewLocati...
```

Comment: Is your server using the right database? The error message is quite clear:  `NewLocationModel_location.point_ptr_id does not exist`

Comment: The error shows that you haven't run makemigrations and migrate correctly because the FK to `Point` doesn't exist in your db.

Comment: @Hoenie you're right, sorry, didn't notice it.

Comment: No worries, that happens ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates the column does not exist.

```
column NewLocationModel_location.point_ptr_id does not exist
```

Make sure you are using the correct database...